# Libpng install c++ with visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, libpng

I am making a game that runs on OS X and Windows. The game loads textures fine on Mac but on Windows the header `png.h` isn't available. How would I go about loading a .png image on windows in c++? I can use this code:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
//code to load png image on osx here...
//i have this code working on mac
#else
//code to load png image on windows here...
//i need help writing this code or installing libpng
#endif
```

What's the easiest way to get this to run properly on Windows? I spent over 3 hours trying to get `libpng` on visual studio with no success. I am using glut. thanks